# Neutral Wire Become Hot After Power Connection

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, light-fixture, light

[image][image]Lightswitch A Has 5 wires within its switch box. Two Black wires (B1, B2), One red (R1), and two neutral (W1, W2).

B1 is input power. B2 is a feeder wire for downstream lights. R1 sends power to a light from Lightswitch A.

If B1 and B2 are connected, W1 becomes hot. If W1 and W2 are connected, then both W1 and W2 become hot while B1 and B2 are connected. If B1 and B2 are not connected, neither W1, W2 are hot.

If B1 is connected to Lightswitch A, the lights targeted by Lightswitch A function without issue. This is the case whether W1, W2 are connected.

If B1, B2 are connected and W1 and W2 are connected, further connections downstream from Lightswitch A (not the lights mentioned above) appear not to function because both W1 and W2 are hot. Downstream connections do appear to be getting power without issue, however don't appear to have appropriate neutral from voltage testing.

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You need to take some pictures and indicate where the wires are coming from, trace them out. If you don't know where they are coming from, we can possibly know.

Comment: 3 way switch and Switch Loop

Comment: if it is a switch loop, then wouldn't it imply I can keep the whites seperated and downstream lights should function?

Comment: Correct .......

Comment: ok ill go wire it up and see how it functions.

Comment: if I connect the black wires, the light connected to the current switch functions without issue. One white becomes hot, the other does not. If I go and test downstream appliances, they also have a hot white wire. If I do not connect the black wires, the downstream appliances do not recieve any power. I have updated the picture.

Comment: If you break the neutral return back to the panel, then the 'downstream' neutral will read as 'hot' if there's anything connected & switched on.